# x86 ABI : Should DF flag be always 0?

Tags: gcc, abi

I was writing `memcpy` & `memmove` for C module (compiled with x86 gcc 4.8.2).They're using string instructions:

```
cld
rep movsb
```

or

```
std
rep movsb
```

However, the second one didn't work. After some tries, I tried putting this code.

```
std
rep movsb
cld    ; this
```

Then everything works well... But why?? ABI says DF is always 0? Why?

And if so, can I remove `cld` in the first code?

```
; cld <-- removed
rep movsb
```

Comment: cld is pretty cheap, so perhaps best to be safe. I would consult Agner Fog's reference tomes (google him) to see if rep movsb etc is the best way to do it on your processor. Some recent machines have given new life to these old rep instructions so that they perform well. I wouldn't try to write your own memcpy for the general case though as very high performance library routines such as Agner Fog's own tuned one are very much non-trivial.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While not technically the definitive word in such things, it's close: [agner fog](http://www.agner.org/optimize) wrote a series on optimization that includes information about ABI specifications that includes information about different architectures, operating systems, compilers, etc.  I found a similar statement to what I'm about to quote in an x86-64 ABI, but its title suggests it may be AMD specific so I skipped that reference.

Quoting from their document [Calling conventions for different C++ compilers](http://www.agner.org/optimize/calling_conventions.pdf):

> Direction flag
>   The rules for the direction flag is the same in all systems. The direction flag is cleared by default. If the direction flag is set, then it must be cleared again *before any call or return*. Some compilers and subroutine libraries rely on the direction flag always being clear (Microsoft, Watcom, Digital Mars) while other systems use the double-safe strategy of always leaving the direction flag cleared, *but not relying on receiving it cleared* (Borland, Gnu).

... with emphasis added to prove what I'm about to say: example code you've seen with `cld` before any `movsb` instructions is a CYA move in case someone else violated the ABI.

Comment: Thanks for a great answer to a very old question! By the way, what does "*CYA*" mean?

Comment: *C*over *Y*our *A*(rear end)